# API Display ES6 Using Template Strings

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

```js
function createNode(element) {
      return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el);
}

function submitInfo(){
    const ul = document.getElementById("display");
    fetch('http://sample_website.com/api/announcements', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization : 'Bearer 8huihjgogugggi'},      
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data =>  { 
        let announcements = data;
        console.log(announcements);
        return announcements.map(function(announcement) {
            let li = createNode('li'),
                span = createNode('span');
            span.innerHTML = `${announcement.data.data[0].title}`;
            append(li, span);
            append(ul, li);

        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Announcement</h1>
<div id="display"></div>
 <input type="button" value="Get Data!" onclick="submitInfo();">
 </body>
```

Here i have a problem using template strings to create a list element. Using data from an API, I need to output these to the browser. Please check my codes on what is the problem. Check also the image for reference.

Comment: `announcements` is not an array, but as usual with your questions it's extremely hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @Pointy. It says announcement.map is not a function

Comment: @Pointy. Maybe you can help me how to fix Li element in template strings

Comment: Right, which means that the value of `announcements` is not an object that has the `.map()` function in its prototype chain.

Comment: @Pointy. Maybe i don't need to write .map function. Is there other way to write Li element in template strings. I just need to output these as an Li element using template strings in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

function submitInfo(){

```
fetch('http://example_website.com/api/announcements', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization : 'Bearer eeeewiqhhroiqworqiorqwihr'},      
})
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => { console.log(data)

        const output = document.getElementById("display");
        output.innerHTML = `<ul>
                        <li>${data.data.data[0].title}</li>
                        <li>${data.data.data[0].body}</li> 
                        </ul>`;

})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

}